# Lottie Animation setAnimation() results IllegalStateException

Tags: android, lottie

I want to check Lottie lib for both iOS and Android today, I made a simple indicator animation in after effect and export it to .json file and it just works on iOS. When I test the same file on Android I got the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.lottietest/com.test.lottietest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView.setAnimation(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

here is my activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mtids.lottietest.MainActivity">

    <view
        class="com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView"
        id="@+id/animationView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="animate"
        android:text="animate" />
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LottieAnimationView anim;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        anim = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.animationView);
        anim.setAnimation("indicator.json");
    }

    public void animate(View view) {
        anim.loop(true);
        anim.playAnimation();
    }
}
```

Comment: debug this line `anim = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.animationView);` it returns null may be library synch issue or view not declared correctly in xml.

Comment: I believe it is `View`, not `view`

Comment: well i think the issue is with indicator.json file path, if any use this lib before, plz could you mention where exactly to put the .josn file ??

Comment: @TimCastelijns, it's [<view>](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Comment: @AliAdil, are you sure you have successfully imported Lottie dependency?

Comment: @azizbekian yes, my friend

Comment: It should not be an issue, but just try `<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView />` instead of `<view class="com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView>`. Also try to navigate to `LottieAnimationView`.

Comment: I already try it and got the same error !, i will try to use version 1.5.3 instead of  2.0.0

Comment: i'v changed the id property to android : id="@+id/animationView" instead of id="@+id/animationView" only , and the error message become  
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find file indicator.json

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> i'v changed the id property to android : id="@+id/animationView" instead of id="@+id/animationView" only , and the error message become java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find file indicator.json

As you correctly noticed, first you should change `id` to `android:id`.

Secondly, from the [sources of `setAnimation(String)`](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/LottieAnimationView.java#L272):

> Sets the animation from a file in the assets directory.

Obviously, you have no file named "indicator.json" in `assets` directory.

Comment: Well, as i said before the issue was in the .json file it should be under app/src/main/assets/ now its working ... thank u @azizbekian

Answer (score 6):

You have to make a raw resource directory and then paste the "indicator.json" file there.

Change :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LottieAnimationView anim;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        anim = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.animationView);
        anim.setAnimation("indicator.json");
    }

    public void animate(View view) {
        anim.loop(true);
        anim.playAnimation();
    }
}
```

To:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LottieAnimationView anim;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        anim = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.animationView);
        anim.setAnimation(R.raw.indicator);
    }

    public void animate(View view) {
        anim.loop(true);
        anim.playAnimation();
    }
}
```

And in the xml file :

Change:

```
<view
        class="com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView"
        id="@+id/animationView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

To:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animationView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

These changes worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this line to programatically change the animation.

```
// i have used data binding

binding.animationView.setAnimation(R.raw.paymentsuccess);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update version to:

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.3'
```